# WHY does my cpu usage goes to 99%, when my C# application starts listening on tcp socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, cpu-usage

I created a TCP socket listening application . As I run my program,  CPU usage goes up to 99%

```
        NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = null;
        while (!stopRecieving)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (nStream.CanRead)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[800000];
                nStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
                recvDt = ascii.GetString(buffer);
                //       --++ Normal msg
                if (recvDt.Contains("--++"))
                {
                    string d = "--++";
                    recvDt = recvDt.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());


                    obj.SetSomeLab(recvDt, port );

                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

If some one could tell me how to decrease CPU usage?
Regards,

Comment: What happens if you do `Thread.Sleep(10000);`? Please show entire listening method code

Comment: Can you post more of your 'recieve at socket' code?

Comment: Thread.Sleep is rarely needed in socket code - the (multiple) async APIs can offload this to callbacks, often via IOCP. However, everything that matters here is in `//recieve at socket` ... You haven't shown us any useful code to look at - so how could we possibly comment?

Comment: lol - I've just seen your previous question (now deleted); when people asked for some relevant code, they didn't mean just an empty comment. The problem you are seeing relates to **what your code is doing**. Should we guess? We can almost certainly help, but : we need something to look at

Comment: i added the complete code, kindly have a look

Comment: some one told me to add a little delay to decrease cpu usage,
   Thread.Sleep() is for delay.

Answer (score 1):

another approach would be to use async pattern:

```
public void StartListening() {
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[0],11000);

    Console.WriteLine("Local address and port : {0}",localEP.ToString());

    Socket listener = new Socket( localEP.Address.AddressFamily,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

    try {
        listener.Bind(localEP);
        listener.Listen(10);

        while (true) {
            allDone.Reset();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(SocketListener.acceptCallback), 
                listener );

            allDone.WaitOne();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine( "Closing the listener...");
}

public void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    allDone.Set();

    Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Additional code to read data goes here.  
}
```

see more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx